# Изменение величины (от-до) исходя из другой величины (от-до)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите в вопросе, может кто сталкивался.

Не могу сам додуматься как написать в математической формуле решение. 
Есть величины длины и высоты от которых будет меняться третье число (оно допустим от 0 до 8), именно, что от 0 до 8 иначе перебор или недобор.

То есть, есть величины:

```
from random import*
width     #длина  - величина изменяемая пользователем (от 0 до 640)
height    #высота - величина изменяемая пользователем (от 0 до 360)
width_max = 640     #длина - величина постоянная
height_max = 360    #высота- величина постоянная
size      # размер от 0 до 8ми (который мы будем получать имея входные данные "длины" и "высоты")
```

И необходимо изменять Size исходя из значения width и height, чем больше тем больше другое...

Если кто-то поможет в написании формулы или подскажет может уже есть готовая функция (изменения значения от-до исходя из значений от-до)
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: `width` и `hight` - это **две** величины, таким образом, как понять, что значит ваше **«чем больше width и height»**? Их сумма? Произведение? 5*width + 2*hight? Что-то другое? И где **граница** между size=5 и size=6? Когда вы хотите получить ответ, должно уточнить (может быть, тоже для себя), что вы собственно хотите. Иначе рискуете, что ваш вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: @MarianD, согласен, надо более развернуто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно рассмотреть такой вариант. Width от 0 до 4, height от 0 до 4.

```
   max_width =640
   max_height =360
   bit_width=max_width//4
   bit_height=max_height//4

   d_width= width /bit_width
   d_height= height /bit height
   size = d_width + d height
   size_int = round (size, 0)
```

Вообще чтобы перевести отрезок [0,a] в [0,b] нужно все элементы [0,a] умножить на b/a.

Для пилообразной функции с максимумом в 300 и нулем в 150 и 450 получаем

```
   d_width = 4-4*abs(witdh-300)/150
```

Comment: спасибо, тоже очень хороший вариант

Comment: а как сделать примерно то же самое, только чтобы точкой отчета была середина значений «width и height»
Чтобы значение Size росло если (width = 300) width = 300 и 0
И Size = 0 если width 150

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то как-то так:

```
max_width = 640
max_height = 360
max_size = 8
size = (max_size + 1) * width * height // (max_width * max_height + 1)
```

Comment: похоже идеальный вариант, большое спасибо, переделал под себя, чтобы можно находить очень большое количество остатков, и потом перевести в дробное...
Спасибо